# Java multithreading without thread class or runnable interface

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to achieve multithreading in Java without using thread class or runnable interface?

Comment: why not lambda expression? `()->System.out.println("Hello");`

Comment: This isn't a question for *Have you tried anything?* comments, is it?

Comment: @Deadpool wouldn't lambda expressions use one of the mentioned classes internally?

Comment: Considering you have to run *something* in order to run *anything*, and that something will run on a thread, no.

Comment: it uses internally but i'm not sure what he is asking exactly @deHaar

Comment: @Deadpool yes, this slight unclearness is a problem in the question.

Comment: I understand that streams support some optional parallelism magic, but I haven't looked enough into it to see what it involves.

Comment: You can use `Executors` and other classes from [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) , but internally these also use the `Thread` class

Comment: @Deadpool, I don't understand about "why not lambda expression?" A lambda expression is a convenient, compact way of creating an object that implements some particular, functional interface. How your program then uses the object (e.g., if your program hands the object to some library routine that will cause its function to be called in some other thread) is completely unrelated to the fact that you used a lambda to create the object.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, You can use a lambda expression to avoid having to type the word "Runnable" in your source code, but that does not mean that the lambda is a "substitute for `Runnable`." If you write a lambda expression with the right type signature in the place where a `Runnable` is expected, then the lambda expression will _create_ a new `Runnable` instance every time it is evaluated.

Comment: @SolomonSlow now we have the problem, but I *as programmer* am not "using thread class"... otherwise it is impossible since everything is using at least one `Thread` instance (which also has a `Runnable` field, I believe)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, I guess it depends on what you think "use" means. You probably could have a lively debate about that with somebody on english.stackexchange.com, but I'll probably take a pass on that one.

Comment: @SolomonSlow sorry, I thought that was clear in my comment ("now we have the problem")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thread in a Java program must have an associated `Thread` instance, and every `Thread` "has" a `Runnable`.* There's no way around it. It's just how Java works. You can call `Thread.currentThread()` from anywhere in your program and it will always return a reference to the `Thread` object that controls the thread that is executing your code.

That being said, there are plenty of different ways (e.g., thread pools, thread factories, the streams API) that the library will create new `Thread` objects on your program's behalf so that you can get multiple threads running your code without you having to explicitly write `new Thread(...)` anywhere.

---

* Scare quotes around "has" because sometimes the `Thread` instance is its own `Runnable`.